# Angular not able to get the attribute contents in view

Tags: angular, angular5

The **product.component.ts** is a component from where I'm fetching the data from the backend using the httpclient Service but when I display the product variable in the ngOninit() I get undefined, so none of them are displayed in the view but when the value of product variable is logged using console.log() I get all the list of products from the backend am I doing anything wrong here? Below is the code.

**product.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Product} from '../app-models/product.model';
import {ProductService} from '../app-services/product.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-product-listing',
  templateUrl: './product-listing.component.html'
})
export class ProductListingComponent implements OnInit {
  product: Product[];

  constructor(private productService: ProductService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.productService.getAllProducts().subscribe(
      response => {
        this.product = response;
        console.log(JSON.stringfy(response));
      },
      error => {
        console.log('error:: ' + JSON.stringify(error));
      }
    );
  }
}
```

**product.component.html**

```
<div class="featured_slider_item" *ngFor="let p of product">
   <div class="border_active"></div>
   <div class="product_item discount d-flex flex-column align-items-center justify-content-center text-center">
      <div class="product_image d-flex flex-column align-items-center justify-content-center"><img src="../../assets/images/featured_1.png" alt=""></div>
      <div class="product_content">
         <div class="product_price discount">&#8377; {{ p.offerPrice }}<span><del>&#8377; {{ p.price }}</del></span></div>
         <div class="product_name"><div><a>{{ p.code }}</a></div>
      </div>
      <div class="product_extras">
        <div class="product_color">
          <input type="radio" checked name="product_color" style="background:#b19c83">
          <input type="radio" name="product_color" style="background:#000000">
          <input type="radio" name="product_color" style="background:#999999">
        </div>
        <button class="product_cart_button" (click)="addToCart( p )">Add to Cart</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="product_fav"><i class="fas fa-heart"></i></div>
    <ul class="product_marks">
      <li class="product_mark product_discount">-25%</li>
      <li class="product_mark product_new">new</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

**productService.ts**

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {ApplicationProperties} from '../properties/applicationproperties';
import {Product} from '../app-models/product.model';

@Injectable()
export class ProductService {
  private getAllProductsUrl = ApplicationProperties.BackendRestUrl + 'getAllProducts';

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

  getAllProducts() {
    return this.httpClient.get<Product[]> (this.getAllProductsUrl);
  }
}
```

**product.model.ts**

```
export interface Product {
  id: number;
  code: string;
  description: string;
  stock: number;
  price: number;
  offerPrice: number;
  image: Blob;
  createdOn: string;
  lastUpdatedOn: string;
}
```

Comment: *when I display the product variable in the ngOninit()* ... *but when the value of product variable is logged using console.log()*. What is the difference between those two. Which precise line of code prints undefined? There is only one console.log() in the code you posted, and it's in ngOninit

Comment: Do you see the data on console.log(JSON.stringfy(response));?

Comment: ya the data is displayed on console.log(JSON.stringfy(response)); but when I do console.log(JSON.stringfy(this.product)); on the next line get undefined and also no data in the view

Comment: can you post what you see on console.log(JSON.stringfy(this.product));

Comment: And post the actual code containing the line of code that prints the product and which printds undefined. Explaining the behavior of unknown code isn't easy.

Comment: Actually what happens is when I used the code console.log(JSON.stringfy(this.product)); outside the subscribe method I get undefined I have attached screenshots plz refer to them https://img42.com/@BZTHr

Comment: Ah, so that explains it all. Of course it's undefined there. An HTTP call is **asynchronous** The products are only initialized later, in the callback function passed to subscribe(). If the call was synchronous, you wouldn't have to bother with observables: the service would return the array directly rather than an observable. So what you're seeing is absolutely normal and expected.

Comment: So how should the code be modify to display the products in the view

Comment: If it doesn't, it's probably that you have an error in thetemplate. Look for errors in the console. Start much smaller: just add {{ product | json }}. Then use a simple ngFor to display each product, Also choose a better name: if it's an array containing many products, name the variable `products`, not `product`. Bad names lead to mistakes and misunderstanding.

Comment: Hey, the issue was with some js which was included in the template, removed and it works! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an external JS included which was stopping the products from being displayed. The code works fine!

Answer (score -1):

In your service.ts where you have written the http get request you can make the following changes

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {ApplicationProperties} from '../properties/applicationproperties';
import {Product} from '../app-models/product.model';
import {map} from 'rxjs/add/operator/map;
@Injectable()
export class ProductService {
 result:Product[];
private getAllProductsUrl = ApplicationProperties.BackendRestUrl + 'getAllProducts';

constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

getAllProducts() {
  return this.httpClient.get<Product[]> (this.getAllProductsUrl).map(res=>this.result=res.json().data);
  }
}
```

Comment: No, this doesn't make sense. An array of products doesn't have any json() method. That wouldn't even compile.

Comment: im getting the data form the backend as json and also in angular6 it is the default